Dúvidas Sobre o Uso do Genitivo e Ablativo em Latim: Adjunto Adnominal vs. Adjunto Adverbial
Estou dando início nos meus estudos em Latim pelo livro de Napoleão Mendes de Almeida e me veio uma dúvida na hora de estudar os casos. Para o caso genitivo, Napoleão usa o exemplo da "casa de Pedro", onde "de Pedro" é o adjunto adnominal restritivo -- ele explica que geralmente se utiliza o "de" para ligar o adjunto ao substantivo (nome) e que este adjunto quase sempre dá ideia de posse (aliás, qual outra ideia ela poderia dar, já que é "quase sempre"?); no caso ablativo, ele fala sobre este ser o adjunto adverbial do português e dá o exemplo de uma "espécie" de adjunto adverbial de matéria, que utiliza a preposição "de" também, como no exemplo "Anel de ouro". Esses dois exemplos de cada caso, parece-me que na verdade são a mesma coisa, porque ambos são restritivos (especificam o substantivo), tanto dizendo a quem pertence ou de que matéria é.
Então, como saber quando é um adjunto adnominal restritivo ou adjunto adverbial?
(Eu sei que há outras preposições que podem ser usadas com o adjunto adverbial, mas o caso do "de" realmente dificulta a coisa, principalmente porque não há verbo no exemplo do "Anel de ouro").

Podes incluir alguns dos exemplos em latim dados por Napoleão Mendes? Aliás, um adjunto adnominal acompanha um substantivo, adjuntos adverbiais acompanham verbos ou orações. "De ouro" não é adjunto adverbial pois acompanha um substantivo. "De ouro" em "feito de ouro" é adjunto adverbial de matéria.

@Quaestoria, infelizmente Napoleão não deixa nenhum exemplo em Latim, já que essa parte do conteúdo é somente par dar noções básicas.

Bem, então não sei. Mas digo com confiança que "de ouro" em "anel de ouro" não é adjunto adverbial — ad-vérbio, ao verbo —, não há verbo nenhum ali. O ablativo latino, de cabeça, tipicamente corresponde com as preposições 'de' e 'desde', genitivo com 'de' e 'em', e por aí vai.

@Quaestoria, e como diferenciar o "de" de ablativo para o "de" de genitivo?

De acordo com o significado. Os próprios casos latinos eram usados de acordo com a semântica (ablativo de matéria, dativo de propósito, por aí vai), não só pela sintaxe (o acusativo rege a preposição inter, o ablativo a preposição cum).
